# Using FFmpeg via PowerShell - Correct use of dashes and quotes in arguments

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell

StackExchange has been the first place for me to look for answers for a long time - unfortunately, I could not find any (working) solution for my current problem, so I opened this question.

What I'm trying to do is to create a PowerShell-Script (I am quite new to PS) to automatically process a list of files (i.e. all MP4-files that share the same folder as the script) via FFmpeg.

**TL;DR: What I can't get to work: Using filter-commands (`-vf "iamafilterargument"`) that include variables.**

The command I'm trying to get working when hand-written into cmd would be:

```
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -an -c:v libx264 -crf 16 -preset veryslow -vf "drawtext=fontsize=12:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='<input_filename>':bordercolor=black:borderw=2:fontcolor=white:x=(w-tw)/2:y=5:alpha=0.5" <output_filename>.mkv
```

Via cmd, this works just as intended. Now my PS-Script:

```
$encoder = "C:\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe"
$dateien = Get-ChildItem .\*.mp4
$dateinamen = ForEach-Object {$dateien.BaseName}    
    for($i=0; $i -lt $dateien.Length; $i++){
        $filterbefehl = " -i " + $dateien[$i] + " -an -map_metadata -1 -vf=`"drawtext=fontsize=12:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text=" + $dateinamen[$i] + ":bordercolor=black:borderw=2:fontcolor=white:x=(w-tw)/2:y=5:alpha=0.5`" -c:v libx264 -intra -crf 16 -hide_banner " + $dateinamen[$i] + ".mkv"
        Start-Process -FilePath $encoder -ArgumentList $filterbefehl -NoNewWindow; pause
    }
    Write-Host "Done!"
```

However, I get this error message from FFmpeg:
(I left the filename in intentionally - the whole file is called "cam4_2017-03-01_2238.mp4".)

> Unrecognized option
>   'vf=drawtext=fontsize=12:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text=cam4_2017-03-01_2238:bordercolor=black:borderw=2:fontcolor=white:x=(w-tw)/2:y=5:alpha=0.5'.
>   Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

I tried all sorts of things:

- Using double-doublequotes ("") instead of backticks (`")
- Using `&$encoder $filterbefehl`
- Including the content of $filterbefehl into `-ArgumentList`
- Using singlequotes instead of doublequotes for $filterbefehl

The above result is the closest thing to a working script I could accomplish up to now. Most of my other attempts failed because I could not work out how to get proper quotations (both "" and `" didn't work).

Used Software:
 - Win10 Pro (though I would like it to work on Win >=7)
 - Powershell 5.1(Build 14393)
 - FFmpeg-binariy from Zeranoe's website - latest version
   (20170225-7e4f32f) (using 3.2.2 didn't make a difference)

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: There should be no `=` in `-vf=`

Comment: Oops, you're right, @Mulvya - I used it a thousand times and this is the first time that I included an equation mark :-D
Now it outputs an error about my `fontfile` - I will check that later.

Pretty embarassing stuff - failing because of a beginner's mistake ;-)

Comment: @flolilo You asked a very detailed question, far beyond the quality of most first posts on SU. You should not feel embarrassed. Is the error regarding `fontfile` the path to the font?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @root ;-)
FFmpeg's error was `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file` - It took me some time to figure out that this error appears if your working directory isn't on the system disk (e.g. D:\Path).
So my code now involves:

`$system_volume = "C:\"
$files_volume = "D:\Path"
cd $system_volume
<ffmpeg command as above, with FULL PATH for input and output files>
cd $files_volume
<additional commands>`

(the whole script is very long, as this was only one part of the whole thing - later on, i concatenate the files, ...)

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mulvya's answer was correct - when correcting `-vf="<params>"` to `-vf "<params>"`, the code works.

*On a sidenote:* If someone else tries to work with drawtext and gets the error `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file` from FFmpeg - Check if your working directory isn't on the system disk (e.g. D:\Path). If so, change your code to something along:

```
$system_volume = "C:\"
$files_volume = "D:\Path"
cd $system_volume <ffmpeg drawtext-command as above, with FULL PATH for input and output files>
cd $files_volume <additional commands>
```

Thanks again for the help!